# Surface integral (divergens theorem) parameterization

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

$\int \int \bar{F}\bar{N}dS$

$\bar{F} =(4x^{3}+y^{2}-z , x^{2}+y^{3}+z , x^{3}+z+1 )$

$\gamma : z=4-4x^{2}-y^{2}$ $z\geq 0$ , Normal is pointing upward.

My attempt : 
$r(s,t)= (s,t,4-4s^{2}-t^{2})$ but when I took the cross product of the partials dot normal vector it did not simplify.

Is there a better way to parametrize the surface ? 
Or should this be done using divergense theorem insteed?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why even parametrize the surface when you know that the normal is $\langle -z_x,-z_y,1 \rangle$.

Comment: cant we close it and then use divergence ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint** Use divergence theorem , you will get easy boundries when you switch to elliptical polar coordinates on the tripple integral you get.

$x=\frac{rcos\theta }{2}$

$y=rsin\theta  $

$z =z $

$0\leq r\leq 2$

$0\leq \theta \leq 2\pi $

$0\leq z\leq 4$